# Does the photo-use apply to profile pictures?

Tags: discussion, photos

We have [this other meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/how-should-the-use-of-copyrighted-photos-be-addressed) that addresses the use of copyrighted photos in posts. I am wondering if this applies to profile images or not.

Example: I have Image #1 as my profile picture and I want to change it to #2. Is it fine and legal to do here? (I just asked this as an example, I am not really going to change it)

**Image 1:**

[image]

Image my own

**Image 2:**
[image]
Source [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lufthansa_Boeing_747-8_%2816278574162%29.jpg)

Comment: Is there any reason to think that it wouldn't? The general [Stack T&C](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) just refer to "content", irrespective of where it is. And I don't see any obvious reason why this site would want to have different rules for pictures in posts vs. anywhere else.

Comment: @Pondlife Right, but there are some accounts here linked to a person's external account, particularly Google, where the use of copyrighted pictures as profile pictures is not really "bad" and when linked, it would pop up here as the photo unless it is changed.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point that I never thought about. But [meta.SE has](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127271/i-created-my-stack-overflow-account-using-google-openid-and-the-profile-picture), apparently they don't come from Google at all. That might not answer your question, but it's still interesting.

Comment: @Pondlife People can change their picture if they want, but some like me just keep the same one.