# Should answers be flagged if they use diagrams without a source?

Tags: discussion, answers

In an answer to a recent question, the answerer referred to a diagram that I'm pretty sure was not something he/she created.  I'll refrain from mentioning the specific answer to avoid any conflict, *but I did wonder whether answers like this should be flagged.*

I am aware of [this discussion](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-we-ask-users-for-proper-image-attribution), which does conclude that images should be sourced.  OTH, in the accepted answer for that thread, @Pondlife does say that "you cannot expect moderators to take care of this".

Does this mean we should just allow the voting process to police this?

Comment: Flagged for what? The question about image attribution seems to cover it, I don't see why diagrams would be a special case. People *should* provide proper attribution, others can edit to include that, but it will not be policed by moderators.

Comment: Unless you want to raise a "moderator only" flag, moderators won't get involved [with exceptions to the rule].

Comment: And even if you do raise a moderator flag, that's not really what moderators signed up for.

Comment: I'm with @fooot on this... If you're going to argue that diagrams should be a special case, then please discuss *why* they should be a special case not covered by the discussion on "images" in general.